# Django: Any difference between `QuerySet.__nonzero__` and `QuerySet.exists`?

Tags: python, django

I see that the `QuerySet` class has 2 different methods that seem to serve the same purpose (unless I'm mistaken): `.__nonzero__` and `.exists`. (Yes, I know that `.__nonzero__` is used by `bool`.)

My question: Why do the 2 methods have different implementation if they both just check whether there's any object in the queryset?

The Django documentation says about `QuerySet.__nonzero__`:

> Note: Don't use this if all you want to do is determine if at least
>   one result exists, and don't need the actual objects. It's more
>   efficient to use exists() (see below).

(I didn't find anything insightful "below".)

Why does `QuerySet.__nonzero__` have a non-efficient implementation? Is it trying to achieve something different than `.exists`? What is the reason that the Django developers don't do `__nonzero__ = exists`?

Comment: I would assume that `__nonzero__` evaluates the `QuerySet` while `exists` does a special query to the database backend instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does QuerySet.**nonzero** have a non-efficient implementation? Is it trying to achieve something different than .exists? What is the reason that the Django developers don't do **nonzero** = exists?

I think it's because `exists` is only efficient under certain circumstances.

Imagine this common scenario if `__nonzero__` had the "efficient" implementation.

```
foos = Foo.objects.filter(bar='baz')

if foos:   # nonzero() calls exists() which causes extra query
           # even though the QS is already going to be evaluated
           # which in my projects is a common pattern. 
   print "Yay for foos!"
   for foo in foos:
       print foo
```

`__nonzero__` also evaluates the query and stores results in cache. That means all results are stored in memory.

`exists` only cares about 1 row, and doesn't even instantiate a django object or even store its result in cache.

It seems useful if you are *only* checking if something exists, and don't need the data in any way.

> Why don't the devs make `__nonzero__` == `exists`?

Because `exists` assumes you don't care about the results. If `__nonzero__` called `exists`, we'd have no results. If `exists` called `__nonzero__`, we'd collect results (potentially a lot) just to check if a row exists or not.

Examples:

```
bool( Foo.objects.filter(user=user) )  
# calls __nonzero__, evaluates, converts all fields to python objects 
# and stores in queryset._result_cache


Foo.objects.filter(user=user).exists()
# stores nothing, and query only returns one row.
# less data from DB and less python overhead generating django model instances.
```

Comment: You can interpret the decision as "explicit is better than implicit". Django only does the query you asked for. This applies to `count()` and `__len__` as well. The DB optimisation docs also have a useful example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/#don-t-overuse-count-and-exists