# Why would Django get request with long url lock python?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a strange error using the built in webserver in Django (haven't tested against Apache as I'm in active development).  I have a url pattern that works for short url parameters (e.g. Chalk%20Hill), but locks up python on this one

```
http://localhost:8000/chargeback/checkDuplicateProject/Bexar%20Street%20Phase%20IV%20Brigham%20Ln%20to%20Myrtle%20St
```

The get request just says pending, and never returns, and I have to force quit python to get the server to function again.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
In continuing testing, it's strange, if I just enter the url, it returns the correct json response.  Then it locks python.  While I'm in the website, though, it never returns, and locks python.

urls:

```
url(r'^chargeback/checkDuplicateProject/(?P<aProjectName>(\w+)((\s)?(-)?(\w+)?)*)/$', 'chargeback.views.isProjectDuplicate'),
```

views:

```
def isProjectDuplicate(request, aProjectName):
    #count the number of matching project names
    p = Project.objects.filter(projectName__exact = aProjectName).count()

    #if > 0, the project is a duplicate
    if p > 0:
        return HttpResponse('{"results":["Duplicate"]}', mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('{"results":["Not Duplicate"]}', mimetype='application/json')
```

Model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    projectName = models.TextField('project name')
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.projectName
```

Comment: Could you post more information? urls.py, view declaration

Comment: @msc Forgot to mention, if it matters, there are only 5 records in that database table right now.

Comment: It's not good the way you construct your url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are going to check whether `aProjectName` already exists in the database, there's no need for you to make the regex so complicated.

I suggest you simplify the regex to

```
url(r'^chargeback/checkDuplicateProject/(?P<aProjectName>[\w+\s-]*)/$', 'chargeback.views.isProjectDuplicate'),
```

For a further explanation, see the question [*url regex keeps django busy/crashing*](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/Bxq9i0mttSc/DEz7S7M8lxAJ) on the django-users group.

Comment: Perfect.  +1 for the link to the why, which was very helpful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is spot on about the regex, but since we're discussing optimization, I thought I should note that the code for checking whether a project exists could be modified to generate a much quicker query, especially in other contexts where you could be counting millions of rows needlessly. Call this 'best practices' advice, if you will.

```
p = Project.objects.filter(projectName__exact = aProjectName).count()
if p > 0:
```

could instead be

```
if Project.objects.filter(project_name__iexact=aProjectName).exists():
```

for two reasons.

First, you're not using `p` for anything so there's no need to store it as a variable as it increases readability and `p` is an obscure variable name and [the best code is no code at all](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/05/the-best-code-is-no-code-at-all.html).

Secondly, this way we only ask for a single row instead of saving the results to the queryset cache. Please see the official [Queryset API docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists), [a related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368205/django-any-difference-between-queryset-nonzero-and-queryset-exists/14369747#14369747) and [the discussion about the latter on the django-developers group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-developers/L4irIYGPUWM/wK7fQ1q_SsYJ).

Additionally, it is customary in python (and Django, naturally) to name your fields lower_cased_separated_by_underscores. Please see more about this on the Python Style Guide [(PEP 8)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for this.  I'll make the suggested change.  As you can probably tell, I'm new to both Django and Python :-)